# HTML5 GamePad API returning inccorect or stuck axes

Tags: html, angular, web, gamepad, gamepad-api

I am having a problem where when I am using the html5 gamepad API and are polling Gamepad.axes for the controllers trigger values occasionally (usually when I give the controller a bunch of random inputs) the values in the axes array will become stuck. As in the gamepad.axes will say that one of the triggers is fully pushed down even if the controller is not being touched.

Stack:

Angular 6.1

node 12

Firefox 74

What I have tried:
I have tried a lot of things that could be related to our code a couple of main things that I tried:

1. Using the gamepad timestamp to check if it is stuck

This will work but also cause other problems. The time stamp does not get updated when it gets stuck in a position but it also doesn't get updated when the user is holding down one of the triggers, causing a false positive that it is stuck.

2. Seeing if I could force the array to update

There is no built in method yet for gamepad api and the axes array is immutable .

3. Increase the polling rate

I don't need a very high poll rate so it was set at every 100ms but lowering it down to 8ms seemed to have fixed the problem! The only problem is I don't know why, I are hitting the gamepad.axes array more often but I can't think of any reason that this would cause the array to be updated more accurately than before.

Is there any reason for this? Thanks!

Comment: it is maybe related to your gamepad. Did you try another one ?. Probably your gamepad creates noise from some buttons..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `getAnimationFrame()` to poll your gamepad. One theory might be that your gamepad aggressively falls asleep, maybe if the battery is really low? Another theory is simply a hardware defect. If you can physically crack your gamepad open, try cleaning the analog stick mechanism.